# can't see aditional themes in control panel

Tags: themes, localhost, xampp

I installed wp 4.2.2 on xampp localhost - multisite, following this article
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/

xampp is surely ok, because it works a year without a problem.

The new installation is wordpress only.

Installation seems ok, but starting dashboard - Appearance - Themes I can see just current theme (Twenty Sixteen), without any button to load additional themes.

I checked wp-content folder - there are three default themes there.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a few things causing it. Have you altered any core files or wp-config in anyway?

Are the themes definitely valid, they have a style.css file with the required information filled in?

I'd recommend setting up a completely fresh WordPress installation. Copy each theme in one at a time and make sure they show up.

If they do, it's most likely something wrong with your core setup/wp-config file.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of files/db, download again Wordpress (4.4.2), overwrite all files and check again.

Check the php version, folder structure, reset files permission and/or update Xampp if needed.

If not working, try the backup in Mamp (OSX) or EasyPHP (Win) to exclude a Xampp problem. If you want take a look at https://serverpress.com